# Showing user's iTunes Profile in iOS App

Tags: ios, uiwebview, itunes

I want to show [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/seka-aleksic/id309535625) iTunes link on the iPhone's screen.
Should I use the `UIWebView` or something else?

```
    import UIKit

    class MusicViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var itunesWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL (string: "https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/artist/seka-aleksic/id309535625?mt=1&app=music")
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        itunesWebView.loadRequest(requestObj)

        /* INITIAL SETUP FOR COLOURS & FONTS */

        // Change the Navigation Bar Font to Lato
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
            [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
                NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lato-Semibold", size: 20)!]

        // Set the Navigation Bar Text Color to White
        navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        // Set the Background of the Table View
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
        let image = UIImage(named: "main_menu_background")!
        imageView.image = image
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
        /* INITIAL SETUP FOR COLOURS & FONTS */

    }


}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can ! 
Use this: https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us/?urlDesc=&country=us
It creates an iTunes link ready for sharing.
Hope it help you

If you have a problem with it, please ask me

EDIT:

**UIWebView Load URL**

With a link(your case):

```
let url = NSURL (string: "https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/clash-of-clans/id529479190?mt=8");
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
yourWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

With an HTML code:

```
var htmlString:String! = "<br /><h2>Blaaaaa</h2>"
yourWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

My example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7z8xuidqedwhy2e/DragosStrugarHelp.zip?dl=0